# How can i get ip address of client connected to remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, remote-desktop

I have this environment:

I have one windows server with many client that will connect to it in remote desktop.

For each client it creates a new session asa it connect to rdesktiop.

What i need is to create a file on the Document And Settings folder relative to the client connected in which i store the ip address of client connected.

Using `netstat -n | find ":3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"` i reach to get all ip address of clients connected but not the only one i need.

Can someone give me a simple solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question on StackOverflow, maybe it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510093/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-desktop-client

Answer (score 0):

This Powershell snippet when run in a Powershell session on the Terminal Server should give you the IP address of the current client.

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational'; ID=1149; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-31);} | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject] @{User=$_.Properties[0].Value; IPAddress=$_.Properties[2].Value; TimeCreated=$_.TimeCreated;}} | Where-Object User -eq $env:USERNAME | Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress
```